# Get cluster object from ID Amazon EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, emr

I fired up an EMR cluster through the GUI screens. After the cluster got fired up,I could see the ID. How do I get an object of class Cluster that represents that the cluster with that ID? I am using Java for interacting with EMR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just run a single command in order to get a cluster's identity. The following is a working example of an algorithm that reads the ID of all the failed clusters.

```
AWSCredentials credentials;
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myAccessKey", "mySecretKey");

AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emrClient;
emrClient = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);
emrClient.setEndpoint("elasticmapreduce.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");

ListClustersRequest req;
req = new ListClustersRequest().withClusterStates(ClusterState.TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS);

ListClustersResult res;
res = emrClient.listClusters(req);

int size  = res.getClusters().size();

System.out.println("***************** CLUSTER LIST ***************");
System.out.println("*** Size: " + size);

for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){           
    String clusterID = res.getClusters().get(i).getId();
    System.out.println(">>> Cluster: " + clusterID);    
}
```

Note the followed steps:

- Generate an EMR client to access Amazon's services using your own credentials
- Create a cluster request indicating the status filter (several other filters exist)
- Get the actual list of chosen clusters
- Get the ID of each cluster inside a for loop

As what it refers to your specific question, I am afraid it is not possible to get the actual object of the cluster. Instead, the API allows to get the information summary of a concrete cluster (which is used in the provided code above). You can still, however, issue commands such as the termination of a cluster, for example:

```
clusterId  //Defined in the code above

TerminateJobFlowsRequest terminate;
terminate = new TerminateJobFlowsRequest().withJobFlowIds(Arrays.asList(new String[] {clusterId});

emrClient.terminateJobFlows(terminate);
```